# i want a Dos batch file which can display which databases are running

Tags: database, batch-file

i have installed Sql Server 2008, Oracle 10I and DB2, i want a Dos batch file which can display which databases are running.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a pretty complicated batch file to write. You will need to use other tools to determine which of the database server types you mentioned are running. You would be better off writing an application to do this.